# D3.js collapsible tree show top N children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to only show top N children sorted by their size for the collapsible tree. I am using this [collapsible tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/shubhgo/80323b7f3881f874c02f), but instead of showing all the children I want to show only like top 5 or whatever N I specify.

One one I can think of doing is to keep 2 copy of data. One copy will have all the children, and the second copy will only have the top N children. And then build the tree with only the 2nd copy. I don't know if there is another better d3.js way to do it.

```js
    var data = {
    "key": "parent",
    "size": 100,
    "children" :[
        {
            "key" : "child1",
            "size": 10
        },
        {
            "key" : "child2",
            "size": 4
        },
        {
            "key" : "child3",
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "key" : "child4",
            "size": 2
        },
        {
            "key" : "child5",
            "size": 3
        },
        {
            "key" : "child6",
            "size": 20
        },
        {
            "key" : "child7",
            "size": 4
        },
        {
            "key" : "child8",
            "size": 1
        },
        {
            "key" : "child9",
            "size": 5
        },
        {
            "key" : "child10",
            "size": 50
        }
    ]
};
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 1060 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 1200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,// animation duration
    root;// stores the tree structure in json format

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var edge_weight = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, 100])
                    .range([0, 100]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

// adding the svg to the html structure
var svg = d3.select("div#viz").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

edge_weight.domain([0,data.size]);
root = data;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

/**
 * Updates the node.
 * cloppases and expands the node bases on the structure of the source
 * all 'children' nodes are expanded and '_children' nodes collapsed
 * @param {json structure} source
 */
function update(source) {
  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodesâ€¦
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return edge_weight(d.size/2);})
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the linksâ€¦
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d){
       return 1;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .attr("stroke", function(d){ 
       return '#0950D0';});

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d){
      /* calculating the top shift */
      var source = {x: d.source.x - edge_weight(calculateLinkSourcePosition(d)), y: d.source.y};
      var target = {x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y};
      return diagonal({source: source, target: target});
      })
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d){
       return edge_weight(d.target.size);
      });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

/**
 * Calculates the source y-axis position of the link.
 * @param {json structure} link
 */
function calculateLinkSourcePosition(link) {
 targetID = link.target.id;
 var childrenNumber = link.source.children.length;
 var widthAbove = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < childrenNumber; i++)
 {
  if (link.source.children[i].id == targetID)
  {
   // we are done
   widthAbove = widthAbove + link.source.children[i].size/2;
   break;
  }else {
   // keep adding
   widthAbove = widthAbove + link.source.children[i].size
  }
 }
 return link.source.size/2 - widthAbove;
}

/*
 * Toggle children on click.
 * @param {node} d
 */ 
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  /*stroke: steelblue;*/
  opacity: 0.3;
  /*stroke-width: 1.5px;*/
}

#levels{
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="viz"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript array functions `sort` and `slice` to restrict the data to the top N children of each node, before the tree diagram is generated. To do this, include the following code at the top of the function `update()`:

```
    //...
    function update(source) {

        function topN(node, N) {
            if (node.children) {
                // The node has children
                node.children.sort(d3.descending);  // Array sorted in-place
                node.children = node.children.slice(0, N);

                // Now run the function on each child:
                node.children.forEach(function (x) {
                    topN(x, N);
                });
            }
        }
        topN(source, 5);

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        //...
```